# call DjangoRestFramework DetailAPIView() from another view

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views

**solution from @brian-destura below**

The DRF test client does not work, but the django.test.client does. Odd (?) because it's a DRF APIView being called.

```
    from django.test import Client
    client = Client()
    result = client.get('/api/place/6873947')
    print(result.json)
```

---

I have a DRF DetailAPIView() that returns a complex serializer json response to external API queries, so in the browser, and via curl etc. `http://localhost:8000/api/place/6873947/` returns a big JSON object. All good. The url entry in the 'api' app looks like this

`path('place/<int:pk>/', views.PlaceDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='place-detail'),`

I need to use that in another, function-based view, so first I tried using both django.test.Client and rest_framework.test.APIClient, e.g.

```
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
from django.urls import reverse
client = APIClient()
url = '/api/place/6873947/'
res = client.get(url)
```

That gets an empty result. With django Client:

```
from django.test import Client
c=Client()
```

Then

- `res = c.get('/api/place?pk=6873947')`
  and
- `res = c.get('/api/place/', {'pk': 6873947})`

Both return "as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

I've tried other approaches in my IDE, picked up in StackOverflow, starting with

```
from api.views import PlaceDetailAPIView
pid = 6873947
from django.test import Client
from django.http import HttpRequest
from places.models import Place
request = HttpRequest()
request.method='GET'
request.GET = {"pk": pid}
```

Then

- `res = PlaceDetailAPIView.as_view({"pk": pid})`

  - "as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"
- `res = PlaceDetailAPIView.as_view()(request=request)`

  - "Expected view PlaceDetailAPIView to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly"
- `res = PlaceDetailAPIView.as_view()(request=request._request)`

  - "HttpRequest' object has no attribute '_request"

I must be missing something basic, but hours of thrashing has gotten me nowhere - ideas?

Comment: You have to place the pk on the url, so on django client: `res = c.get('/api/place/6873947')`

Comment: Sheesh. I had tried that for the rest_framework.test.APICLient (1st example above), but not the django.test.Client -- Thanks! `res.json` gets what I need. Will edit and credit.